# Jquery Hide Div element if length greater then

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I Want to hide element if another div's length is greater than 0, otherwise show the div

i have this code but it is not working for me :(

```
 <div id="myid">90.00</div>
 <div class="myclass">99.00</div>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           if($('#myid').length > 2){
            $('.myclass').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *another div's lengt is greater then two symbol*?

Comment: Oh sorry  , i mean if  div id greater then 0 hide class

Comment: Do you mean to have an id?!! OR id's value length be greater than one number?!

Comment: Length function will return you the total number of divisions with the id of "mydiv" and not the length of that division. Please rephrase what exactly do you mean by the length of division

Comment: check code below please

Answer (score 2):

First edit your question by your new detail;

Then set your condition inside your `updateTotalFinal` function

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function updateTotalFinal(){
    const subtotalValue = +jQuery('.wpforms-payment-total').text().replace(/^[^0-9,.]+/, "").match( /^[0-9,.]+/g, '');
    let totalValue = subtotalValue;
    const totalFinalElem = jQuery("#totalfinal");
    
  
    
    jQuery("input.change-total:checked").each(function() {
      const $this = jQuery(this);
      if ($this.is("[data-method=add]")) {
        totalValue = totalValue * $this.data("amount");
      } else if ($this.is("[data-method=multiply]")) {
        totalValue += subtotalValue * $this.data("amount");
      }
    });
    
    totalFinalElem.text(`${totalValue.toFixed(2)}`);
    
    // IF YOU WANT CHECK THAT ANY VALUE FOR totalfinal IS EXIST USE THIS
   if($('#totalfinal').text().length ){
      $('.wpforms-payment-total').hide();
    }
    
    // IF YOU WANT CHECK THAT totalfinal IS GREATHER THAN ZERO USE THIS
    /* if(parseInt( $('#totalfinal').text()) > 0 ){
      $('.wpforms-payment-total').hide();
    } */
  }
  
  jQuery("input.change-total").on("change", function() {
    updateTotalFinal();
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
     97
    </div>
     
    
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="change-total"  name="myBox2" size="12" data-amount="0.15" data-method="multiply" value="100" />
      With Two Coat + 15%
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="change-total" name="myBox3" size="12" id="myCheck" data-amount="0.9" data-method="add" />
      With My Own Paint
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <b><span id="totalfinal"></span></b>
```

Comment: Thank You and sorry for stupid question.  Can i ask one more thing i want to display only 2 symbol afther decimal.  is this will work ? ` if($('#totalfinal').text(finalprice.toFixed(2)).length ){` ?

Comment: Yourwelcome. If `finalprice`  means `totalValue` you must use `toFixed(2)` here `totalFinalElem.text(${totalValue.toFixed(2)})` and `$('#totalfinal').text().length` works again

Answer (score 0):

i have this code and want to hide
class "wpforms-payment-total" when "totalfinal" is calculated

```
<div class="wpforms-payment-total">
     97
    </div>
     
    
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="change-total"  name="myBox2" size="12" data-amount="0.15" data-method="multiply" value="100" />
      With Two Coat + 15%
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="change-total" name="myBox3" size="12" id="myCheck" data-amount="0.9" data-method="add" />
      With My Own Paint
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <b><span id="totalfinal"></span></b>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function updateTotalFinal(){
    const subtotalValue = +jQuery('.wpforms-payment-total').text().replace(/^[^0-9,.]+/, "").match( /^[0-9,.]+/g, '');
    let totalValue = subtotalValue;
    const totalFinalElem = jQuery("#totalfinal");
    
  
    
    jQuery("input.change-total:checked").each(function() {
      const $this = jQuery(this);
      if ($this.is("[data-method=add]")) {
        totalValue = totalValue * $this.data("amount");
      } else if ($this.is("[data-method=multiply]")) {
        totalValue += subtotalValue * $this.data("amount");
      }
    });
    
    totalFinalElem.text(`$ ${totalValue}`);
  }
  
  jQuery("input.change-total").on("change", function() {
    updateTotalFinal();
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  if($('#totalfinal').text() > 0){
      $('.myclass').hide();
  }
});
```